# Selenium: Can I tunnel through an *External* HTTP/SOCKS proxy over Firefox?

Tags: proxy, selenium, socks

I know Selenium Server acts AS a proxy. But I want to know if I can instruct a test to connect through to either a SOCKS or plain http proxy, eg: **Tuenneling through an external Proxy**. (It's so hard to search for because the word proxy just shows how Selenium works, not if it supports this feature....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -DsocksProxyHost=socks.******.*** -DsocksProxyPort=1080 while running it .

or

In the MANual , you can find this..
  -proxyInjectionMode: puts you into proxy injection mode, a mode
    where the selenium server acts as a proxy server for all content
    going to the test application.  Under this mode, multiple domains
    can be visited, and the following additional flags are supported:

or
set the settings mentioned above in the system variables..

Yenjoy!